# enter carriage return but don't break a word

Tags: c#, string

I have a block of text where i want to enter carriage return '\n' after every 5 characters and i achieve that already but real problem is I don't want that carriage return break any word, so only carriage return insert when there is a space and next to 5 characters.

```
   StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                char[] t = txtString.ToArray();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (char c in t)
                {
                    s.Append(c);
                    if (i > 4)
                    {
                        s.Append("\n");
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
return s.ToString();
```

For example my string is "Ahead of Liverpool's crunch clash with Manchester United, we have assessed how the two sides compare on the pitch and marked them out of 10 "

so for this string carriage return after 'Ahead' is OK but from there next five characters carriage return break the 'Liverpool' so don't insert carriage return to break the word insert when there is a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another condition to check for the space.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            char[] t = txtString.ToArray();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (char c in t)
            {
                s.Append(c);
                if (i > 4 && c == ' ')
                {
                    s.Append("\n");
                    i = 0;
                }
                i++;
            }
return s.ToString();
```